# VideoFileClip import Error: "ImportError: No module named requests"

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to import VidoFileClip from moviepy.editor.

This is the code:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
```

This is the error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E:\Spring2018\MastersProject\ProjectFiles\Alternate.py", line 7, in <module> from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 31, in <module> from .video.io.downloader import download_webfile
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\downloader.py", line 7, in <module>
import requests
  ImportError: No module named requests
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install requests. Open up a terminal or a command prompt and type

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: that worked thanks a lot

Comment: Why is this necessary? Shouldn't `pip install moviepy` take care of that?

Comment: Because the stacktrace shows an `ImportError`. It can't find the `requests` package. The stracktrace doesn't mention `moviepy`